# How I can repaint QWizard?

Tags: border

I want add the border(for example "1px solid black") to my wizard, but don't know how?
Here is my constructor of the wizard class:

```
{
    // Remove original window frame.
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    // Add new pages to wizard.
    this->setPage(PageIntro, new WizardIntroPage(0));
    this->setPage(PageNewDisk, new WizardCreateNewDiskPage(0));
    ...

    this->setStartId(PageIntro);
    this->setWizardStyle(QWizard::ModernStyle);
    this->setFixedSize(550, 400);
}
```

I try do this in the main function:

```
Wizard* wizard = new Wizard();
wizard->setStyleSheet("border:1px solid black;");
```

But Back, Next, Cancel buttons are distorted. Someone faced with such a problem?